# Scope function gets called and executed multiple times angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a scope function that gets called and executed multiple times. How can i avoid this or how can I stop this?

```
<div class="row">
   <label>Attached Documents</label>        
   <ion-scroll> 
      <img ng-repeat="image in detailedCaseInfo.real_estate_agent_assignment_attachments" ng-src='{{urlForImageDownload(image.filename)}}' ng-click="showImagesDetailed($index)" class="image-list-thumb" height="50px"/>
  </ion-scroll> 
</div>  



$scope.urlForImageDownload = function(imageName) {
    var name = imageName.substr(imageName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log(name)
    console.log(imageName)
    var trueOrigin = AppSettings.baseApiUrl + imageName;
    console.log(trueOrigin)
    return trueOrigin;
  }
```

I know it has to do something with databinding and $digest but i just cant figure out how to make it not execute multiple times.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you have used it with ng-repeat it will be called each time the img tag is created !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't doing anything that you couldn't do simply using a scope variable for the image paths:

JS

```
$scope.imagePath = AppSettings.baseApiUrl;
```

HTML

```
<img ng-repeat="...." ng-src="{{imagePath + image.filename}}">
```